# Generate/Export excel file from Java Play Framework 2.0 List<object>

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, export-to-excel

I need to generate/export a excel file from a table that is generated from a list of objects. I can see that there is a module for Play 1.x but not for Play 2.x and. I found a possible solution but it is written in scala (I think) here: http://aishwaryasinghal.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/generating-excel-in-play-2/

I've tried to implement this but I think my imports doesn't work.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;

public static void generateExcel(List<Infoobject> list) {
        File file = new File("mydata.xlsx");
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
            //Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); Doesn't work either
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
        int rNum = 0;
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rNum);
        int cNum = 0;
        Cell cell = row.createCell(cNum);
        cell.setCellValue("My Cell Value");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }
```

It can't find either XSSFWorkbook, Sheet, Row and Cell. Do you guys know what the problem could be?

Can I use an another solution and just write it in clean Java? Or Javascript maybe?

And I do know that I have to iterate my List later to get some stuff in my excel file. This is just a try to see if it works.

Comment: Do you have the apache-poi library in your classpath? That's where those classes come from.

Comment: If you want to have a more scala-ish experience with generating excel files, you might want to try https://github.com/folone/poi.scala

Comment: Is it only _poi-examples-3.9-20121203.jar_ I should put in the classpath? Eclipse: Properties>Java Build Path>Libraries>Add JAR? Where should I put the file? In play frameworks lib map?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add the dependencies to the `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaJdbc,
    cache,
    javaEbean,
    "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.8",
    "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.9"
)
```

Then, you need to regenerate your project (eg. `play idea`), and run as normal.
The first time you run it will load all the new dependencies from Maven, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Jasper Report it is a good way for exporting data from models into EXCEL file/Report.
If you want some samples i can send you them ;)