# Play Scala can't use a dependency

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, dependency-injection, dependencies

I have some dependencies troubles with my Play Scala API. I want to start doing Excel generation so I found a way to do that but the dependencies don't want to work.

I correctly add them this way :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.8",
   "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.8"
)
```

I recompile everything, even did "sbt clean" > "sbt idea" > "sbt run", the libraries are correctly downloaded, I see them in the "External Libraries" folder, but when I try to use some models, it doesn't find anything.

In the imports, i add a :

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel._
```

The import is found but is in grey which means it's unused. I need the XSSFWorkbook model but if I change the "usermodel._" in "usermodel.XSSFWorkbook" (which is correct), it's red as not found.
In my controller function, it also doesn't find anything, usually IntelliJ suggests some models to import when it's not, but here no.

Have you any solution ? Thanks !

Comment: Not sure on the exact problem, because your dependencies look like those in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470597/generate-export-excel-file-from-java-play-framework-2-0-listobject). You could take a look at [this library](https://github.com/folone/poi.scala) which seems to have wrapped things.

Comment: I check on that ! Thank you